# Vimeo Using API

Tags: vimeo-api

I try to list down my video using the Vimeo simple-api/gallery. The vimeo API works it list down the 20 videos but until I upload the 6 new latest video on that channel. The 6 videos not showing up. It must be 26 videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you will only see 20 items per page.

If you are using the Simple API you can not increase this, you must request the next page (you can read more here: https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/simple#limits).

If you are using the Advanced API you can increase this with the "per_page" parameter (you can try it here: https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods/vimeo.videos.getUploaded/playground).

Comment: Just a heads up, these links are out of date now.

Comment: Correct, the simple and advanced apis are no longer a thing, and pagination is much more straightforward. You can find them at developer.vimeo.com